# Find limit property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfy: $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$    $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the sequence: $$u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n+f(u_n)}{2},u_0=a$$

Research the limit property of this sequence.

I have considered some trick and I must say if $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|$ for some $k< 1$ the problem would be much easier. I can prove that indeed $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(u_n)-u_n=0$. But in the case $k=1$ it seems like any of my trying is meaningless. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x+b,$ where $b$ is any fixed constant. Then, $u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{b}{2}.$ Now, if $b>0$ then the sequence $(u_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ and if  $b<0$ then the sequence $(u_n)$ diverges to $-\infty.$